# Firing JPA listeners on collection field change

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, listener

I am using EntityListeners (`@PreUpdate`) to perform certain actions once my entities change.
However I noticed that changes of a collection inside an entity does not fire the JPA entity listener, that makes sense because the table containing the entity was not changed, but a many to many table was.

Is there a way to make the entity listener fire in case of a collection change?

Comment: Why don't you place the PreUpdate attribute in the child Entity instead of the parent?

Comment: @perissf the table that is being updated is a many to many table that is not mapped as an entity in my code.

Comment: Hi, I noticed the same behaviour using JPA/Hibernate. It is a problem for me since auditing, which is triggered by an EntityListener, does not take place if for example I add a role to a user (many-to-many collection). Did you find a way to workaround this ?

Answer (score 3):

Listeners are fired for versioned entities (see [javax.persistence.Version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Version.html)). Found via this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073342/12039

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the events to be called.  What JPA provider are you using?