# Trigger Hibernate(pre/post)Update Event when Relationship Changes

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have implemented the pre/post event listeners for Hibernate events with one caveat I haven't been able to overcome. I have a `Departments` entity that has a many-to-many relationship back to a `Centers` entity. When assigning a new Center to a Department, I simply invoke:

```
oDepartment.addCenter(oCenter);
entitySave(oDepartment);
```

When this happens, I would expect Hibernate to trigger the preUpdate and postUpdate events since I modified the entity. However, it's never triggered unless a column property is also updated. Updating only a relationship property does not seem to trigger the update events.

Looking through the current Hibernate session, I can't seem to find anything that would allow me to set some sort of flag that would trigger these events to fire.

Thoughts on a way I could get these events to fire?

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate doesn't fire pre/postUpdate events when a collection is changed. 
Instead it will trigger

- preCollectionUpdate/preCollectionRemove/preCollectionRecreate
- postCollectionUpdate/postCollectionRemove/postCollectionRecreate.

This is a known and old bug, you can check [HHH-2616](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2616) and [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4184?jql=text%20~%20%22postupdate%20collection%22).

Either you implement these listeners, or, as a workaround, you can force the postUpdate to be called changing another field on that entity.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fire listeners is to add a @javax.persistence.Version field on your entity. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073342/12039