# Spring MVC EntityListener : No data from join table

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, entity

I have an entity like :

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(ReunionListener.class)
public class Reunion implements Serializable{

private Long id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.DETACH,
                        CascadeType.REFRESH },
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "Reunion_User",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Reunion_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
                 inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
                 )
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
//Getters & setters...
}
```

**ReunionListener** :

```
public class ReunionListener {
@PostPersist
public void reunionPostPersist(Reunion ob) {
System.out.println(ob.getUsers().size())
}
}
```

Here I'm getting the size of the list is "0" but I'm sure I have 1 user in the join table and In my controller I have this :

```
//Reunion
reunion.getUsers().add(user);
rs.saveReunion(reunion);
System.out.println(rs.getReunion(reunion.getId()).getUsers().size())
```

And here I'm getting "1"

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

**EDIT**

For Insertion I'm just implementing JpaRepositiry from spring data jpa :

*DAO :*

```
@Repository
public interface ReunionDAO extends JpaRepository<Reunion, Long> {}
```

*Service :*

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ReunionServiceImpl implements ReunionService {

@Autowired
private ReunionDAO rDAO;

@Override
public void saveReunion(Reunion r) {

    rDAO.save(r);
}
}
```

Comment: where is your insert/save code, add it here

Comment: @javaguy Updated as requested.

Comment: What is the size (number of rows) saved inside database ?

Comment: In the join table I have : Reunion _id : 1 , User_id : 1

Comment: 1 row is saved in the database.

Comment: look here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/110195

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063262/jpa-eventlistener-method-not-called-on-change-to-many-to-many-collection

Comment: Thank you for you help, It seems that it's a bug and It would take a lot of time, I'll just implement it manually and gain my rest of mind :)